# Laravel Godaddy Library

Tags: laravel, composer-php, godaddy-api

I'm trying to install betapeak/laravel-godaddy package / library in my Laravel application but get this error log from console when running composer.

I'm ysing Laravel 7

```
composer require betapeak/laravel-godaddy 

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install betapeak/laravel-godaddy 1.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - Installation request for betapeak/laravel-godaddy ^1.0 -> satisfiable by betapeak/laravel-godaddy[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - betapeak/laravel-godaddy 1.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.3.0|~5.4.0|~5.5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.3.0 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.3.16 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.3.23 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.3.4 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.0 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.13 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.17 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.19 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.27 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.36 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.9 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.0 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.16 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.17 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.2 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.28 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.35 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.36 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.37 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.39 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.40 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.41 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.43 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.44 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.26.1, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.26.1].
```

Comment: Seems like the package is not compatible with laravel 7

Comment: how i can fix it  ?

Answer (score 1):

It says the package requires Laravel 5.x versions.

Well you can send a Pull Request (PR) to the maintainer or use a changed version of the package by you own:

- fork the project at Github
- open `composer.json`, at `illuminate/support` line find `|^7.0`, change it to `|7.*`
- commit to your forked repository and make a PR
- if it don't accept, use the package from your repository

Read official Githun docs to know how to Fork and PR

- [Fork a repo](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo)
- [Creating a pull request from a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork)

Answer (score 0):

This library [betapeak/laravel-godaddy](https://packagist.org/packages/betapeak/laravel-godaddy) only supports laravel up-to  5.8.

Currently you're trying to install it on Laravel 7.

If you must use this library, You can downgrade your laravel to 5.8, But that will likely create more compatibility issues.